# Writing Specific lines and characters from an input file into an output file

Tags: python, file-io, readlines

I have been working with a project that requires I count the number of 1's and 0's 
which describes the effect an amino acid would have in the stability of the peptide. There are about 300 different peptide sequences in the file. I want my code to recognize the start of a peptide sequence from my text file, count its length then count the number of 1's and 0's each amino acid records. so far I have been working to get my code recognize the start of a sequence using its index numbering, here's what I have

```
 input_file01=open (r'C:/Users/12345/Documents/Dr Blan Research/MHC I 17 NOV2016.txt') 
    Output_file01= open ('MHC I 17 NOV2016OUT.txt','w') 
    for line in input_file01:
        templist=line.split()
        a=line[0]
        for i in range(0,len(a)):
            if a[i]==1:
                b=line[0+1]
                index=i
                count=+1
                Output_file01.write(a)
                Output_file01.write(b)
            else:
                break 


Here is an example of the content in the file. I want my code to count the peptide sequence, count the number of 1's and 0's and find their ratios within each peptide seq.                                                                                    

    #   1 - Amino acid number
    #   2 - One letter code
    #   3 - ANCHOR probability value
    #   4 - ANCHOR output
    #   
    1   A         0.3129    0
    2   P         0.4044    0
    3   K         0.5258    1
    4   R         0.6358    1
    5   P         0.7277    1
    6   P         0.7895    1
    7   S         0.8710    1
    8   A         0.9358    1
    9   F         0.9680    1
```

Comment: Please explain the algorithm for counting properly along with some sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: You really need to show a representative portion of the file contents for anyone to help.  And an example of expected output is good too.